# Is it possible to change database connections between changesets in Liquibase?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, gradle, liquibase

I've looked into Liquibase [`changesets`](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/changeset.html), [`customChange`](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/custom-change.html), and [`contexts`](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/contexts.html), but after reading through materials these couple of days, I still haven't found an answer that could help me accomplish what I want to do.

Basically, I have database change scripts that I want to run through Liquibase. This is what I have.

1. `script1.sql`

   - `DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG on TABLE1`
2. `script2.sql`

   - `DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW TABLE1`

`script1.sql` should be run on a certain `DB1`, while `script2.sql` should be run on a certain `DB2`. The database URLs for `DB1` and `DB2` are:

1. `DB1`: `'jdbc:oracle:thin:@db_host:1521:DB1'`
2. `DB2`: `'jdbc:oracle:thin:@db_host:1521:DB2'`

I have the ff. defined in `build.gradle`:

```
liquibase {
  activities {
    main {
      changeLogFile "$projectDir/src/main/db/main-changelogs.xml"
      url 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@db_host:1521:DB1'
      username 'root'
      password 'root'
    }
  }
}
```

My changelog is defined as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<databaseChangeLog  
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
  xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.0.xsd
      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-3.8.xsd">  

    <changeSet id="1" author="bob">  
        <sqlFile dbms="oracle"
          path="my/path/script1.sql" />
    </changeSet>  
    <changeSet id="2" author="bob">  
        <sqlFile dbms="oracle"
          path="my/path/script2.sql" />
    </changeSet>  

</databaseChangeLog>
```

**My question thus is, how do I switch connection between `DB1` and `DB2` within my changelog?**

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, you might want to have 2 different `liquibase.properties` file specifying the database url. Also, if you are using only 1 changelog file, you can make use of [labels](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/labels.html), that will allow only labeled changesets to run against specified database.

Answer (score 0):

I also answered this on the Liquibase forum...

You can’t change connections within an execution of Liquibase.

I would suggest separating into two changelogs and running two Liquibase deployments, one for DB1, and one for DB2.

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old thread but for someone looking for a way, here is what I did

1. Kept the connection string (jdbc url) in the properties to master (or any db of your preferene)

```
Enter the Target database 'url' information
liquibase.command.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;**database=master**;applicationname=LiquibasePoC;encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=false
```

2. Used  tag to flip the database for each changeset. Like this:

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <databaseChangeLog>
       <changeSet author="user" id="BaseObjects">
            **<sql>use liquibasePOC1;</sql> <!-- flip to DB 1 -->**
            <sqlFile dbms="mssql" encoding="UTF-8" endDelimiter="\nGO" path="./changesets/liquibasepocdb/tables/dbo.Table1.sql" 
                    relativeToChangelogFile="false" splitStatements="true" stripComments="true" />
            <sqlFile dbms="mssql" encoding="UTF-8" endDelimiter="\nGO" path="./changesets/liquibasepocdb/tables/dbo.Table2.sql" 
                    relativeToChangelogFile="false" splitStatements="true" stripComments="true" />
            **<sql>use liquibasePOC2;</sql> <!-- flip to DB 2 -->**
            <sqlFile dbms="mssql" encoding="UTF-8" endDelimiter="\nGO" path="./changesets/liquibasepocdb/procedures/dbo.SP1.sql" 
                    relativeToChangelogFile="false" splitStatements="true" stripComments="true" />
            **<sql>use master;</sql> <!-- back to connection string db so that DATACHANGELOG gets updated properly -->**
        </changeSet>
    </databaseChangeLog>
```